# delete an empty S3 bucket using `deleteBucket` method using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to check if a bucket exists, and delete it if it does, if not throw some error.

Using the `AmazonClientBuilder` class, I am using the `doesBucketExist` method to check if a bucket is there, and using the `deleteBucket` method to delete that bucket if it exists. If it doesn't exist state it so.

NOTE: I have made sure I have full access to do all operations on the bucket.

But when I run the code, the output show only the bucket name, but not if it is deleted or not. To verify if bucket is deleted, I am doing a `System.out.println`, so that it shows that the bucket is deleted on the screen.

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception;

public class DeleteBucket
{
    private static String bucketName = "mycalibucket1";
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                 .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                 .build();

        try
        {
            if(s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName))
        {
            System.out.printf("\n",bucketName," exists");
            s3Client.deleteBucket(bucketName);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.printf("\n",bucketName," is deleted.");
            }
        }
        catch(AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            System.out.printf(bucketName," does not exist.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

`mycalibucket1`

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please use loggers using log4j/slf4j instead of so output is better readable

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be throwing an exception other than AmazonS3Exception if you are not reaching the 2nd and 3rd print statements.

Looking at the APi javadoc, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#deleteBucket-java.lang.String-

It looks like the deleteBucket method you are calling may throw 2 different runtime exceptions neither of which derive from AmazonS3Exception.  Try catching com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException which looks to be common to both.  See what that tells you and you maybe able to figure out what is causing the problem.

Docs also note that the bucket must be empty to be deleted.